# How to use django templates to play the audio?

Tags: python, django, html, audio

I want catch a audion in a website, and play the audio in the Django templates.
I use this code to get audio

```
import urllib
import urllib2
def get_sound(goal_word): 
    headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"}
    url = "http://dict.youdao.com/dictvoice"
    word = goal_word
    cuntry = "2" 
    params = {"audio":word, "type":cuntry}
    data = urllib.urlencode(params) 
    request = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    fs = open("temp.wav", 'wb')
    fs.write(response.read())
    fs.close()
```

and I find HTML5 could play audio use

```
<audio></audio>
```

so I add it to my templates

```
    <ul id="nav-one" class="nav">

        <audio id="beep-one" controls="controls" preload="auto">
            <source src="{% static 'audio/beep.wav' %}"></source>
            <source src="{% static 'audio/beep.ogg' %}"></source>
        </audio>

    </ul>
```

But it play nothing,and did not cast error message

and this is my setting.py

```
 STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
 STATICFILES_DIRS = (STATIC_PATH,)
```

my file tree:

```
myproject
----myproject
--------__init__.py
--------settings.py
--------urls.py
--------wsgi.py
----static
---------audio
-------------beep.wav
```

What should do now?

Comment: Check for logging error using the django server output or using django debug toolbar.

Comment: Can you see your html that is rendered from the server? Check it in your browser using "View Page Source".

Comment: It reveal "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)"

Comment: And, we I try to type the resorce‘s  address(  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/voice.png`) to check the static file ,it turn to   `A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.`

Comment: @TianFuguang I am having the same problem, in that it loads half files. Did you find any solution.